# May musicians practice their instruments during Sefirah?

Tags: minhag, sefirat-ha-omer, music, parnassah-livelihood

Although one should not listen to music during Sefirah, may musicians practice their instruments during this time?

Would it matter if their livelihood is or is not dependent on their musical talent (professionals vs. hobbyists)?

Would it matter if they are certain they could survive 7 (or 5) weeks without any adverse effects to their musical talents?

Comment: Does anyone keep avelut minhagim for all 7 weeks? Also if you wish to change my answer to a comment please go ahead.

Comment: @Vram Rav Aharon Lichtenstein does, with the exception of holidays (Pesach, Lag BaOmer etc.). My impression was that is also minhag chabad, but I'm sure someone on this site will confirm or deny that more authoritatively than I.

Comment: @DoubleAA It is also minhag Chabad, with those same exceptions.

Comment: Not to stir any controversy, but it **is** a simply a Humra to refrain music in the Sefira.

Comment: @HachamGabriel Minhag Yisroel Torah hi, and all that.

Comment: @HodofHod can't argue with "and all that" :)

Comment: @HachamGabriel the whole sefira is just a minhag.

Comment: @vram I understand, but when Maran mentions something, it becomes Halacha Lekule Alma. However, when the Magen Avraham mentions a Minhag, it's still just a minhag.

Answer (score 3):

My LOR/LOP did not permit me to practice. Although my livelihood does not depend on it; I don't know what he would have said if yes.

Comment: Did he explain his reasoning?  (Since you and ex-Vram got opposite answers, it would help to get more info.)

Comment: AJew, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for sharing yoiur rabbi's bottom line here! Please do heed @MonicaCellio's suggestion, if you can, to make your answer eve more valuable. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 2):

My [LOR](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/594/759) permitted me to practice instruments during Omer even though my livelihood does not depend on it. I am only an amateur musician, which *possibly* modified the ruling.

Comment: Local orthodox Posek (LOP)

Comment: Did he explain his reasoning?  (Since you and AJew got opposite answers, it would help to get more info.)

Answer (score 2):

I remember seeing Yalkut Yosef that for profession it would be Mutar.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from *Shu"t Kapei Aharon* ([Siman 52](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=210&st=&pgnum=134), first column on page 55b of linked edition- paragraph that starts with ואם), which was written by הרב אהרן הלוי אפשטיין, that one may not practice playing musical instruments during the mourning period of Sefirat HaOmer. (Hacham Ovadia quotes him in Yechave Da'at 1:45.) Perhaps this is only according to those who do not listen/play music all year round except for educational purposes.

Comment: BTW does anyone know who אהרן הלוי אפשטיין was?

Comment: Why do you think _" Perhaps this is only according to those who do not listen/play music all year round except for educational purposes."_ ?

Comment: @HodofHod he kinda says something along those lines in the teshuva. והא
 דל א  הב י א ו  סש ״ מ  וה ר מ ״ א  דב ר  זס  לס ד י ׳  מש ו ס  שה ם
 ס״ ל  מי ק ר  דכ ל  סש ג ס  ג״כ אש ו ר  כלי שיר וז מ ר  כנ ״ ל  **sorry for the bad copy/paste but its from HebrewBooks. I recommend you see the teshuva itself.**